# How to extract keys from a jks keystore in nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption, jks, jose

A node application needs to be able to get different keys from a .jks keystore and use them to sign, verify, encrypt and decrypt JWE tokens. The node-keytool library allows me to load the keystore, but I can't use it as such in the node-jose library to do the operations, which expects a JWK-set.

Is there any way of converting a .jks to a JWK-set? If not, how can I access the keystore so that it is useable in node-jose?